# Cordova Android4.3 bounce effect on elements when swiping

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

This problem was noticed in Android 4.3, on IOS, Blackbarry, A4.4 it is ok. And only in wrapped app, in browser it is also OK.
So there are couple of screens with weird elements behavior when scrolling\swipping page up and down. Its looks like fluid, or delay with re-positioning. +/- 7px up and down while up and down swipping. This effect not all elements but 1-2 blocks on page.

Code is something like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content-block">
           Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="content-block">
           Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="content-block">
           Lorem ipsum with buggy scrolling effect
        </div>
        ....
        <div class="content-block">
           Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.content-block {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

I have tried removing padding, apply hack with .inner * {transform: translate3d(0,0,0)}, according ideas found in Stackofverflow, but no luck.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

p.s. here is screenshot, maybe will help to understand the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ocveuirxxc86chi/stack.jpg?dl=0

Comment: When you say it's OK in browser, are you talking about the device's default browser that's used for the wabviews(i.e. not chrome unless in android 4.4)?

Comment: yes, for Android 4.3. it is Chrome

Comment: As far as I know Chrome is used for the webview only since 4.4... But maybe Chrome is installed by default on your phone and hides the old Webkit browser (maybe you have access to it anyway and can use it to test your app?)

Comment: oh, yep, looks like it was changed to Chrome on our testing device... Will try to find a way to test on stock webview, maybe it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To have the same behaviour for all android 4.0+ devices, you may try to use Crosswalk in addition to Cordova.

With curent builds, the result should be se same as with Kit Kat which is using Chrome as webview.

Basically Crosswalk let's you use the latest version of Cromium as webview instead of the device's default webview.

The upside

- you get the same HTML5/CSS 3 support for all the devices
- you should gain performance
- no more surprise when testing on a new device

The downside

- less easy to setup for the moment
- makes a much bigger apk since you add a version of Chromium to your app
- needs at least android 4.0, so say goodbye to support of android 2.3 phones

Here is a tutorial to migrate an existing project from the default webview to Crosswalk : https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html